# Cannot resolve @Value("${xxx:}") (Spring 4) but can resolve @Value("${xxx}")

Tags: java, spring

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
@Component
public class ServiceTest {
    public static String coreIp;
    public static String corePort;

    @Value("${core_ip}")
    private void setcoreIp(String coreIp) {
    ServiceTest.coreIp = coreIp;
    }
    @Value("${core_port:}")
    private void setcorePort(String corePort) {
    ServiceTest.corePort = corePort;
    }
}
```

I can get the value of coreIp, but I cannot get the value of corePort. This code exists in Spring. When I remove ':' in @Value, it works. When I move this code to Spring MVC ,it can work and I can get both value.

Is there any difference between Spring and SpringMVC when they resolve @Value.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that SpEL `${core_port:}` expects to provide default value for `core_port` property. Therefore, either provide a default value for `core_port` (e.g. `${core_value:3000}`) or rename your property by removing semicolon.

Edit:

Since your `core_port` is String type, then the value will be an empty string.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I did get an empty String. But this  ${core_port:}  should be resolved when it can get value from properties file rather than directly get an empty String.

Comment: @ESTRELLAHUANG Is it possible that `ServiceTest` is out of autoconfiguration scope? Check that.

Comment: but when I remove the ":" in  `@Value(${core_port:})`  . I can get the value of `core_port`

Comment: @ESTRELLAHUANG But then, you don't have default value if you don't provide it in your properties file?

Comment: of course, I add the value in my properties files. But I still get the default value, when I remove the ":", I can get the value. this is really strange